# DNS settings in Aegir

Tags: aegir

I successfully set up Aegir hosting in my Ubuntu based VM. At the time of new site creation I face some problems. I got message saying the new site successfully installed but when i click "Log into site" I get a "page not found error". I understand there will be DNS issue, how can I resolve this?

While trying same thing in my local pc. I get to the new site by modifiying my hosts file.  Is it possible to get the site without altering my hosts file?

Comment: The real answer is that you need to have a basic understanding of the DNS system. Then you need either your own DNS-server, such as BIND, or one at a hosting company. This question is way out of scope for a stackexchange discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Check out item 2 on [this](http://groups.drupal.org/node/24994) page on setting up sites in Aegir.

> Login to your DNS control panel at your domain registrar, or wherever
>   your nameservers are, and setup the DNS for the domain name to point
>   at your Aegir server. It's worth including a wildcard record - ie an
>   'A' record for '*' to resolve to your aegir server - then you can
>   easily setup new sites on subdomains without having to ever setup DNS
>   again!

[This video](http://community.aegirproject.org/content/presentation/screencasts/oct-2011-zero-touch-drupal-deployment-jenkins-aegir-git-fabric-and-) also looks pretty neat, not sure how much it'll help though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VM software, such as VirtualBox? Are you trying to connect to the VM through your host machine?

If it so, then you will need to modify your host file for each new site. On Ubuntu it is simple; just type `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, put in your VM IP, and the site name.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I first installed Aegir on my Ubuntu 16.04. What I just did is edit /etc/hosts and point the Aegir address to localhost like this

```
127.0.0.1 aegir.localhost
```

and it works fine.

Note:- You need to restart your server for this to takes effect.

Hope it helps.